# git checkout <commit> does not show me prior version of code

Tags: git

My understanding of `git checkout <commit>` is that git will restore my working directory to the state it had been in at the time of that prior commit. But this is not what happens at all.  For example:

```
rwilson@855:~/jt$ cat > x.x
1st line
rwilson@855:~/jt$ git add x.x
rwilson@855:~/jt$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) f5df7c2] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 x.x
rwilson@855:~/jt$ cat >> x.x
2nd line
rwilson@855:~/jt$ git log --oneline
f5df7c2 Initial commit
rwilson@855:~/jt$ # I want to go back to old version of x.x now
rwilson@855:~/jt$ git checkout f5df7c2
M   x.x
Note: checking out 'f5df7c2'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at f5df7c2... Initial commit
rwilson@855:~/jt$ cat x.x
1st line
2nd line
```

So my questions are (1) how do I ask `git` to put my working directory in the exact same state it was after my initial commit?  (2) why does `git` allow me to go back to an old commit yet keep local changes?  Who would ever want this mixture of old files (from an old commit) and new unstaged changes?  Seems highly counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your current modifications (adding a line to `x.x`) aren't saved anywhere, and aren't incompatible with the commit f5df7c2.

Therefore, git allows your to move through history without removing your current worktree modifications. Two possibilities :

- Put your modifications aside with `git stash` (you can bring them back later with `git stack pop`
- Remove your modifications altogether with `git checkout .`. With this command, you're sure you have exactly the files you had in the current commit (except if you have staged files)

Comment: What does `git checkout .` do?  I tried it with unstaged changes and it quietly **destroyed** all my modifications (is this recoverable?).  With staged changes it did nothing at all.

Comment: @Fixee No, `git checkout .` will simply destroy all your unstaged changes.

Comment: `git checkout .` restores file to their previously staged version. It is totally unrecoverable.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't committed or stashed them. You are thus allowed to move to previous commits.

You can either `git stash` your changes when you added another line to the file before checking out previous commit or `git commit` them, so that you see your previous version of the file when you checkout your earlier commit.